# pick TxK numpy array from TxN numpy array using TxK column index array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

This is an indirect indexing problem.

It can be solved with a list comprehension.

The question is whether, or, how to solve it within numpy,

When 
  `data.shape` is `(T,N)`
and
  `c.shape`  is `(T,K)`

and each element of `c` is an `int` between 0 and N-1 inclusive, that is, 
each element of `c` is intended to refer to a column number from `data`.

The goal is to obtain `out` where

```
out.shape = (T,K)
```

And for each `i` in `0..(T-1)`

the row `out[i] = [ data[i, c[i,0]] , ... , data[i, c[i,K-1]] ]`

Concrete example:

```
data = np.array([\
       [ 0,  1,  2],\
       [ 3,  4,  5],\
       [ 6,  7,  8],\
       [ 9, 10, 11],\
       [12, 13, 14]])

c = np.array([
      [0, 2],\
      [1, 2],\
      [0, 0],\       
      [1, 1],\       
      [2, 2]])

out should be out = [[0, 2], [4, 5], [6, 6], [10, 10], [14, 14]]
```

The first row of out is [0,2] because the columns chosen are given by c's row 0, they are 0 and 2, and data[0] at columns 0 and 2 are 0 and 2.

The second row of out is [4,5] because the columns chosen are given by c's row 1, they are 1 and 2, and data[1] at columns 1 and 2 is 4 and 5.

Numpy fancy indexing doesn't seem to solve this in an obvious way because indexing data with c (e.g. `data[c]`, `np.take(data,c,axis=1)`  ) always produces a 3 dimensional array.

A list comprehension can solve it:

`out = [ [data[rowidx,i1],data[rowidx,i2]]  for (rowidx, (i1,i2)) in enumerate(c) ]`

if K is 2 I suppose this is marginally OK.  If K is variable, this is not so good.

The list comprehension has to be rewritten for each value K, because it unrolls the columns picked out of `data` by each row of `c`.  It also violates DRY.

Is there a solution based entirely in `numpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid loops with [np.choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html):

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.

data = np.array([\
       [ 0,  1,  2],\
       [ 3,  4,  5],\
       [ 6,  7,  8],\
       [ 9, 10, 11],\
       [12, 13, 14]])

c = np.array([
      [0, 2],\
      [1, 2],\
      [0, 0],\
      [1, 1],\
      [2, 2]])
--

In [2]: np.choose(c, data.T[:,:,np.newaxis])
Out[2]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  6],
       [10, 10],
       [14, 14]])
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't think to use `choose`.

Comment: Yup, it takes a while to wrap your head around its possible uses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible route to a general solution...

Create masks for `data` to select the values for each column of `out`. For example, the first mask could be achieved by writing:

```
>>> np.arange(3) == np.vstack(c[:,0])
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

>>> data[_]
array([ 2,  5,  6, 10, 14])
```

The mask to get the values for the second column of `out`: `np.arange(3) == np.vstack(c[:,1])`.

So, to get the `out` array...

```
>>> mask0 = np.arange(3) == np.vstack(c[:,0])
>>> mask1 = np.arange(3) == np.vstack(c[:,1])
>>> np.vstack((data[mask0], data[mask1])).T
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  6],
       [10, 10],
       [14, 14]])
```

**Edit**: Given arbitrary array widths `K` and `N` you could use a loop to create the masks, so the general construction of the  `out` array might simply look like this:

```
np.vstack([data[np.arange(N) == np.vstack(c[:,i])] for i in range(K)]).T
```

**Edit 2**: A slightly neater solution (though still relying on a loop) is:

```
np.vstack([data[i][c[i]] for i in range(T)])
```

Comment: This is interesting, and I'll have to look up vstack and see what it does....  But it also unfortunately seems to depend on K. K might not always be 2.

Comment: I see... I've edited my answer to adapt to the more general case where `K` might be large. I'll see if I can think of any other way to avoid loops completely...